# Shortening mean line in two level factor within facet panels

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid, geom-hline

I have a factor of time that has two levels, admission and discharge. I'm using `facet_grid` to create four panels in which my continuous Y will be looked at by time. I want to be able to add a mean line to each of the two time levels in each panel. My problem is that the mean line spans the entire width of the panel and I'd like to shorten it to just remain within the area of the dots.

Here is the code:

```
plot <- ggplot(data.in, aes(x=Time, y=Y)) + geom_point()
plot <- plot + facet_grid(.~FacetGroup)
data_hline <- aggregate(data.in$Y~data.in$Time + data.in$FacetGroup, FUN=mean)
plot + geom_hline(data=data_hline, aes(yintercept=Y))
```

[image]

Comment: use `geom_segment` instead of `geom_hline` and supply the x-coordinates of your points to the `aes()` mapping

Comment: You might want to consider `geom_segment`. It will require you to make a data frame of the endpoints of the segments.

Comment: Thanks! That really works! Is there a way to create multiple `geom_segment` statements for each combination, or just go one by one? In other words, creating 8 separate `data.frame`s rather than just being able to do it in one go?

Comment: Have a look at the `group` aesthetic for `geom_segment()`. This allows you to separate your data into multiple plotted elements.